# object Object when entering a value into the input

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

An error appears when entering any value

At first I used class components, but then I started redoing them for functional ones and everything broke.

In my state I get a value like this:title > title:"[object Object] and the last symbol which I entered.

Here is the code

reducer

```
 export const postsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CREATE_POST:
            return {...state, posts: state.posts.concat(action.payload)}
        default:return state
    }
}
```

Action

```
export function createPost(post){
    return{
        type: CREATE_POST,
        payload:post
    }
}
```

and a function in a class component

```
            this.setState(prev => ({
                ...prev, ...{
                    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
                }
            }))
```

so I converted it into a functional one. In setTitle I store the value    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

```
            setTitle(prev => ({
                ...prev, ...{
                    [event.target.name]:event.target.value
                }
            }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how you are referencing value on your input. Given your current `setTitle` operation, if you are referencing `title` like:

```
<input type="text" name="title" onInput={handleInput} value={title} />
```

The problem is that you are turning `title` into an object with your `setTitle` operation. An object with property "title" such as `{ title: "some text" }`. That then get's stringified into `[object Object]`.

You could change `setTitle` to the following to keep it as a flat string:

```
setTitle(e.target.value)
```

Or you could change the structure of your state to be an object of form properties:
// create an object with properties to hold your form values
const [form, setForm] = useState({ title: '' });

```
function handleInput(e) {
  setForm(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  }));
}

// reference specific property on form state object
<input type="text" onInput={handleInput} value={form.title} />
```

Hopefully that helps!